# how we can make pipeline through jenkins and main benefits of pipeline

Tags: jenkins

arted by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\systemsystem
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential afa13f5a-244f-400c-bca4-469cf03339cc
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/arehman23/jenkinfile.git

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\systemsystem # timeout=10
> Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/arehman23/jenkinfile.git
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.32.0.windows.1'
> using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/arehman23/jenkinfile.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/arehman23/jenkinfile.git # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> Avoid second fetch
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit}" # timeout=10
> Checking out Revision d22bdefa28f0aaf24cb5e2f91e295974494db884 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f d22bdefa28f0aaf24cb5e2f91e295974494db884 # timeout=10
> Commit message: "Add files via upload"
> First time build. Skipping changelog.
> Triggering systemsystem » default
> systemsystem » default completed with result SUCCESS
> Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Unfortunately your post does provide wnough information to troubleshoot. Hi! Please provide some context of your problem, show your research effort and code attempt

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately your post does provide wnough information to troubleshoot. Hi! Please provide some context of your problem, show your research effort and code attempt